# Unable to import AWS infrastructure configurartion using terraformer

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to import existing AWS infra configuration using google's [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) and I am unsuccessful due to AWS provider authentication problem. My AWS credentials are MFA enabled and hence i have to use session token.  I failed to find options to enable terraformer to use aws session token params.

Here is the debug logs for the terraformer program.  Could someone help me with this please.  The below is generating empty tf files and states.

```
Master $ terraformer import aws --resources=vpc  --regions=eu-central-1 -c -v
2020/06/02 23:17:53 aws importing region eu-central-1
2020/06/02 23:17:53 aws importing... vpc
2020-06-02T23:17:53.525+0530 [INFO]  plugin: configuring client automatic mTLS
2020-06-02T23:17:53.593+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: starting plugin: path=.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4 args=[.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4]
2020-06-02T23:17:53.597+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin started: path=.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4 pid=47500
2020-06-02T23:17:53.597+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: waiting for RPC address: path=.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4
2020-06-02T23:17:54.254+0530 [INFO]  plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2020-06-02T23:17:54.253+0530
2020-06-02T23:17:54.329+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: using plugin: version=5
2020-06-02T23:17:54.329+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: plugin address: network=unix address=/var/folders/jj/2w6phyrs1fj68ks7ry714z000000gn/T/plugin871781403 timestamp=2020-06-02T23:17:54.328+0530
2020-06-02T23:17:54.586+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: 2020/06/02 23:17:54 [INFO] No assume_role block read from configuration
2020-06-02T23:17:54.586+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: 2020/06/02 23:17:54 [INFO] Building AWS auth structure
2020-06-02T23:17:54.586+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: 2020/06/02 23:17:54 [INFO] Setting AWS metadata API timeout to 100ms
2020-06-02T23:17:56.003+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: 2020/06/02 23:17:55 [INFO] Ignoring AWS metadata API endpoint at default location as it doesn't return any instance-id
2020-06-02T23:17:56.010+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: 2020/06/02 23:17:56 [INFO] AWS Auth provider used: "EnvProvider"
2020-06-02T23:17:56.013+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: 2020/06/02 23:17:56 [DEBUG] Trying to get account information via sts:GetCallerIdentity
2020-06-02T23:17:57.577+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4: 2020/06/02 23:17:57 [DEBUG] Trying to get account information via sts:GetCallerIdentity
2020-06-02T23:17:59.652+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v2.64.0_x4 pid=47500
2020-06-02T23:17:59.652+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
2020/06/02 23:17:59 aws Connecting.... 
2020/06/02 23:17:59 aws save vpc
2020/06/02 23:17:59 aws save tfstate for vpc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem by explicitily setting the environment variable AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=~/.aws/credential

Without the above additional env my setup failed.

Answer (score 0):

terraformer import aws  --resources=apigateway,apigatewayv2 --regions=ap-south-1  -c -v
2023/09/08 19:50:44 aws importing region ap-south-1
2023-09-08T19:50:44.205+0530 [INFO]  plugin: configuring client automatic mTLS
2023-09-08T19:50:44.211+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: starting plugin: path="" args=[""]
2023/09/08 19:50:44 exec: no command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).